# configuring ajax lookup in django ajax_lookup

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-ajax-selects

I was using the [django_ajax](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) library for ajax lookup in one of the form elements.

**The model:**

```
class Alpha(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()
    submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**The form**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    alpha = AutoCompleteSelectField('alpha')

    def __init__(self, loser, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loser = loser
        self.fields['alpha'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'big-text-box'
```

The problem with the current implementation is it shows me all the `alpha` entries, but in the lookup field i want only those `alphas` whose `submitted` is `false`.

**How do I write a selector?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is explained in the [README](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects#readme) of the project, you can achieve your goal using a custom lookup class.

Create a file `lookups.py` (the name is conventional) in your app directory, and define the following class in it:

```
from ajax_select import LookupChannel
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.db.models import Q
from yourapp.models import *

class AlphaLookup(LookupChannel):

    model = Alpha

    def get_query(self,q,request):
        # The real query
        # Here the filter will select only non-submitted entries
        return Alpha.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains = q) & Q(submitted = false)).order_by('name')

    def get_result(self,obj):
        u""" result is the simple text that is the completion of what the person typed """
        return obj.name

    def format_match(self,obj):
        """ (HTML) formatted item for display in the dropdown """
        return escape(obj.name)

    def format_item_display(self,obj):
        """ (HTML) formatted item for displaying item in the selected deck area """
        return escape(obj.name)
```

Note that raw strings should always be escaped with the `escape()` function in `format_match` and `format_item_display`.

The crucial thing, in your case, is the `get_query` method. The filter applied on `Alpha.objects` selects only non-submitted entries.

Do not forget to update your `settings.py` to use the lookup class instead of the default behavior:

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'alpha' : ('yoursite.yourapp.lookups', 'AlphaLookup'),
}
```